# Switching Colums in SQL with a inner join select statement

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I would like to execute the following statement but I think I'm missing something in the syntax in `FROM`

```
UPDATE POSTCODE
SET ZIPCODEA = ZIPCODEB,
SET ZIPCODEB = ZIPCODEA
FROM
POSTCODE pst1 
inner join
POSTCODE pst2
on
pst1.POST_ID = pst2.POST_ID
where
pst1._DT = '2017-03-31'
and pst2.START_DT = '2017-04-30'
and pst1.ZIPCODEA  <> pst2.ZIPCODEA
```

How can i fix this?

Greets,

Answer (score 0):

Change it to `UPDATE pst1`

```
    UPDATE pst1 
    SET ZIPCODEA = pst2.ZIPCODEB, ZIPCODEB = pst2.ZIPCODEA
    FROM POSTCODE pst1 
    INNER JOIN POSTCODE pst2 ON pst1.POST_ID = pst2.POST_ID
    WHERE pst1._DT = '2017-03-31' AND pst2.START_DT = '2017-04-30'
          AND pst1.ZIPCODEA  <> pst2.ZIPCODEA
```

Comment: Need to take out the second `SET`.

Comment: `SET ZIPCODEA =  pst2.ZIPCODEB, ZIPCODEB = pst2.ZIPCODEA`?